# ECS Fargate with load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to make to work Load balancer with ECS.

The only way I could figure out how to connect ECS task to load balancer is to create a Target group for private IP of that task (seems that Fargate services don't have EC2 instances). It works alright until I redeploy container and task changes its IP.

Is there a way to permanently connect a task to load balancer even if the IP gets changed due new deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect the ECS service with the Load Balancer. The ECS service will then register/deregister the ECS task(s) with the load balancer.

Please read the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use AWS CDK to deploy your Fargate stack. There you can configure it simply, here is one example of it: [Visit here to view how to do it in a simple manner with CDK](https://medium.com/@chirag2120787/how-to-deploy-fargate-service-serverless-using-aws-cdk-6ffce384b1ae)